Boost asio for consuming multiple web sockets
I'm trying to read some data from a few web sockets at the same time:

Sockets are independent of each other
Frequency of inputs varies a lot between sockets
Occasionally, I would need to redirect data from one socket to another on certain inputs.

My approach is to await on read operations in parallel using awaitable operator ||.
Consider the following pseudocode:
#include <boost/asio/experimental/awaitable_operators.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio::experimental::awaitable_operators;

auto stream1 = provider->get_stream_type1();
auto stream2 = provider->get_stream_type2();

while (true) {
    auto parallel_group = co_await (stream1->read() || stream2->read());

    const auto completed_index = parallel_group.index();

    std::string response{};

    if (completed_index == 0) response = std::get<0>(parallel_group);
    else if (completed_index == 1) response = std::get<1>(parallel_group);
    else throw std::runtime_error("unknown index");

    process(response);
}

The issue is that operator || cancels all outstanding operations when any op succeeds. In my case, I would need to reconnect websocket back, which is rather expensive and does not sound right in general. What I'm doing wrong? What would be a better approach?

you can use operator&& instead, or not make the parallel group at all (just co_spawn separate operations, since, you know, they are separate).
Further Thought
How you planned to fulfill your requirements ("Occasionally, I would need to redirect data from one socket to another on certain inputs") is unclear to me.
I think you accidentally work on a too-low level of abstraction here. What you want parallelized is not individual read operations, but rather the entire websocket sessions.
Once you do, you might use channels to coordinate traffic between sessions.

Thanks for reminding me about channels, I totally forgot about them. I haven't tried it yet, but spawning and relying on channels indeed sounds like a better way.

As for  operator&&, I think it won't work here - it would wait until all ops are finished, but what happens, if one web socket is not active at the moment? We would just hang there waiting for nothing.

This is exactly why I say I think you're parallellizing on the wrong level of abstraction. Ideally you parallellize logical sessions, or even restartable sessions in case you need reconnect logic.
